# Windows SSD, Ubuntu HDD UEFI Partitioning

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have a question with the partitioning for installing Ubuntu. I have Windows on my SSD and I want Ubuntu on my HDD.

When I get into the Systeminformations in Windows it says my BIOS-Mode is "UEFI". 
On my SSD (256GB) I have 3 Partitions. 400MB EFI-Systempartition/Windows (C:) 231,58GB Startpartition, Primarypartition etc./918MB OEM-Partition. 
I have decreased my HDD (1TB). I have a Data1(D:) 785,03GB as Primary Partition and 146,49GB not assigned or free space.

I want to have a Dual Boot menu for Windows and Linux. And Linux should be installed on the 146,49GB not assgined space. Which Partition do I have to add? Like home, root or swap. I'm new to Linux. excuse my ignorance. Best regards

Comment: Default install will use ESP - efi system partition on SSD. That is not an issue if you are ok with that, they share it just fine. But I like to at least have an ESP on all drives, so it could be configured to boot without other drive. new installs now use swap file, so swap partition not required.  Be sure drive is gpt partitioned, but if not gpt use tools to convert or it will be erased. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace  Backups of Windows & all data are required for any system change.

Answer (score 1):

## Step-by-Step

*Warning:* Do **NOT** do any partitioning on the Windows side, use the Ubuntu installer instead.

### Downloads

- go to this website : https://rufus.ie/ and grab rufus (an iso-to-usb-burner tool)
- go to https://ubuntu.com/ and grab the 18.04 LTS version of Ubuntu if you don't like to upgrade often or use 19.04 if you like to upgrade yearly, it's what I use personally.

### Prepare the USB key and to reboot

- plug in a usb key (*key*, not external drive) of 4GB or above into a USB port on your PC case or laptop. Copy all data you might want to keep from this key, **it's contents will be completely wiped**.
- start `rufus and select the Ibuntu ISO, your USB key, GPT mode and UEFI mode.
- Click on start.

Open a CMD as an administrator (right click on the icon and you'll have that option), type:

```
powercfg -h off
```

now you may open up "reset" from start, this will open up the settings as below:

[image: windows settings]

choose "restart now" this will allow you to choose what boot media you want to restart to.

Once you restart you'll be greeted with this screen (click "Install Ubuntu"):
[image: reboot select media]

and select your USB.

If you don't have this screen and have a simple reboot, you may interupt at the bios level to choose the boot media or even enter the BIOS and change to boot order to have your USB key first.

in that case be sure to select the one that says "UEFI" or "EFI" in the name of the usb. this means it will boot the USB in UEFI mode.

### Ubuntu installer steps

once you've booted on the USB you'll be greeted by this screen:

[image: ubuntu install greet screen]

at this point you'll be able to follow the steps they are pretty intuitive

when it asks you how you want to install ubuntu in regards to the windows it automatically detected, you'll be able to choose "install allongside..."

and at this step you should choose your secondary hard drive from the drop down menu this way it installs there and not on your SSD :)

[image: select drive in drop-down]

there done! easy, right?

The dual-boot will be handled by grub, it is the first thing you'll see when you start your computer.

Do not under any circumstance try to replace grub with windows boot loader, you'll have a much better time customizing grub to your liking as this user can attest : [GRUB4DOS error after installing Kubuntu 19.04 and replacing GRUB with Windows 10 bootloader on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150704/grub4dos-error-after-installing-kubuntu-19-04-and-replacing-grub-with-windows-10)

Comment: En Anglais, on ne met pas d' espace avant le `:`, installe un vérificateur d' urthographe Anglais, **+1** puisque c'est une bonne réponse *maintenant*.  **;P** Also, if you disagree with any of this, [Ping me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)  **0:-)**