# Difference "alongside Windows 10" and "alongside Windows Boot Manager"

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, 20.04

In all guides I found online, it always says "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10" during installation, with the next step beeing to manage partitions.

In my current installation it says "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" with the next step beeing "Install now".

What is the difference between the two? Do I chose between Windows Boot Manager and Grub?

During the installation of Windows 10, I left 100+GB unallocated for Ubuntu 20.04.

My goal is a Dual Boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 with the last beeing the default (automaticly start when no input after a few seconds when promted to chose the OS on start up)

EDIT: My question is not " Grub vs Windows boot manager"! I would prefer Grub, so in addition to the question above:
When using "Something else" what partitions do I create? I dont want to destroy or corrupt Windows 10! (Please let me now if I should rather ask a new question)

Comment: This related question might help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/86979/grub-or-windows-bootloader-for-dual-boot

Comment: Thank you for the comment, changed my question

Comment: I usually like the 'something else' option myself, gives you more control.  You saved 100GBs so during install you can format that partition ext4 or what you want, and install to that partition as /.  Make sure you know your partitions perfectly and do not mix them up.  Good idea to make backup first in case of oops.

Comment: @ChrisF Maybe this question might help you then: https://askubuntu.com/a/1009318/1060824